# Draw route using coordinates from API

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview

I am using transportAPI to get routes from one point to another. I intend to draw the route once selected in a mapview. One a preferred route is selected, i iterate through into it's array to get all the coordinates.

The issue is I can't draw the route using the MKPolyline. My code below;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

  //  NSLog(@"selected route: %@",selectedRoute.routeParts);
    NSMutableArray * cordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i = 0;i < selectedRoute.routeParts.count; i++)
    {
        NSMutableArray * cords =[[selectedRoute.routeParts objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"coordinates"];

         for (int c = 0;c < cords.count; c++)
         {

             double latitude = [[[cords objectAtIndex:c]objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue];
             double longitude = [[[cords objectAtIndex:c]objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue];
             CLLocation * location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
             [cordArray addObject:location];
             NSLog(@"coordiantes %@",cordArray);
         }
    }

            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[cordArray.count];
            //int i = 0;
            int numPoints = [cordArray count];
            for (int i = 0; i<numPoints;i++)
            {
                CLLocation * current = [cordArray objectAtIndex:i];
                coordinates[i] = current.coordinate;
            }

            // create a polyline with all cooridnates
            self.polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:numPoints];
            [self.mapView addOverlay:self.polyline];
            [mapView setDelegate:self];
}


- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];

        renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        renderer.lineWidth   = 3;

        return renderer;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

The snippet of the coordinates array;

```
oordiantes (
    "<+51.51756000,-0.12033000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/16/14, 10:04:19 PM Greenwich Mean Time"
)
2014-12-16 22:04:19.545 MeetUp[16434:1366070] coordiantes (
    "<+51.51756000,-0.12033000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/16/14, 10:04:19 PM Greenwich Mean Time",
    "<+51.51865000,-0.12089000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/16/14, 10:04:19 PM Greenwich Mean Time"
)
2014-12-16 22:04:19.547 MeetUp[16434:1366070] coordiantes (
    "<+51.51756000,-0.12033000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/16/14, 10:04:19 PM Greenwich Mean Time",
    "<+51.51865000,-0.12089000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/16/14, 10:04:19 PM Greenwich Mean Time",
    "<+51.51912000,-0.12129000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/16/14, 10:04:19 PM Greenwich Mean Time"
)
```

I reckon the coordinates returned should only be as so for example:

```
[+51.51756000,-0.12033000]
[51.51865000,-0.12089000]
[+51.51912000,-0.12129000]
```

What i'm i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your map's delegate *before* adding the overlay, ex:

```
// create a polyline with all cooridnates
self.polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:numPoints];
[mapView setDelegate:self]; // <-- move this line to before addOverlay
[self.mapView addOverlay:self.polyline];
```

And as for your `coordiantes` array log, it's correct.

Comment: that worked like a charm, silly me, thanks you. If I wanted to zoom in on the points how do I implement that? thanks

Comment: @DrPatience Check out `setRegion:animated:`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setRegion:animated: